# Erlang: receive statement with multiple timeout clauses

Tags: erlang

Is it possible for a receive statement to have multiple timeout clauses, and if so, what is the correct syntax?

I want to do something like

```
foo(Timout1, Timeout2) ->
    receive
    after
        Timeout1 ->
            doSomething1();
        Timeout2 ->
            doSomething2()
    end.
```

where, depending on which of `Timeout1` or `Timeout2` is smaller, `doSomething1()` or `doSomething2` is called.  However, the above code causes a syntax error.

If, as I'm beginning to suspect, this is not possible, what is the best way to achieve the same outcome in a suitable Erlangy manner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to use timer:sleep(Timeout) instead of empty receive statements for readability.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't included any receive clauses because they weren't relevant for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. Just decide what to do before receive.

```
foo(Timeout1, Timeout2) ->
    {Timeout, ToDo} = if Timeout1 < Timeout2 -> {Timout1, fun doSomething1/0};
                         true -> {Timeout2, fun doSomething2/0} end,
    receive
    after Timeout -> ToDo()
    end.
```

or

```
foo(Timeout1, Timeout2) when Timeout1 < Timeout2 ->
    receive
    after Timeout1 -> doSomething1()
    end;
foo(_, Timeout2) ->
    receive
    after Timeout2 -> doSomething2()
    end.
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Any idea why Erlang lacks multiple timeout clauses?  To me they would seem to make the code cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: @grifaton Simple because it can be done in other way (above or use `timer:send_after` as jldupont suggested). It doesn't even work as pattern match, branch can be chosen outside "match" as mine solution shows. And at last they are keeping language as small as possible because it is the right way (and it is one reason why I like it).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a combination of 'gen_fsm' and 'timer:send_after'.